# Ignore all text after some sentence in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
text = "Hi, this a simple test. For more information: bla balasfafa nureahreuahre";
```

I want to ignore all the text after `For more information:`, so that the text will be

```
text ="Hi, this a simple test. For more information:";
```

The issue for me is that I don't know the index / position where `For more information:` begins, there can be a lot of words before the word `For`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it would be good if you can show us what you have tried till now.

Comment: split the string based on colon(:)

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri, and what happens if there are more colons in the string? That won't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simpliest way to do this is

```
string input = "Hi, this a simple test. For more information: bla balasfafa nureahreuahre";
string[] array = input.Split(new string[] { "For more information:" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string output = array[0] + "For more information:";
```

or

```
string input = "Hi, this a simple test. For more information: bla balasfafa nureahreuahre";
int lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf("For more information:");
var res = input.Substring(0, lastIndex + 21);
```